# Angular Calendar and Incomplete Rendering

Tags: angular, calendar, angular2-changedetection

I am using Angular Calendar module on Angular 4.0. Now the problem that I am facing is of incomplete rendering of calendar when I add events to it. When I click on events then after a while the calendar appears completely. I have investigated it on internet and found it something related to change detection but I am unable to implement it.

Here is bit of my code:

```
  view: string = 'month';

  viewDate: Date = new Date();
  refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  events = [];
  clickedDate: Date;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.loadEvents();

  }

  loadEvents(): any {

    let data = [{
      title: 'Editable event',
      color: colors.yellow,
      start: new Date(),
      actions: [
        {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>',
          onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
            console.log('Edit event', event);
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Deletable event',
      color: colors.blue,
      start: new Date(),
      actions: [
        {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>',
          onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
            this.events = this.events.filter(iEvent => iEvent !== event);
            console.log('Event deleted', event);
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Non editable and deletable event',
      color: colors.red,
      start: new Date()
    }
    ];


    for (let d of data) {
      this.events.push(d);

    }

    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.refresh.next();
  }//load events end
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <div
              class="btn btn-primary"
              mwlCalendarPreviousView
              [view]="view"
              [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
              (viewDateChange)="activeDayIsOpen = false">
              Previous
            </div>
            <div
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              mwlCalendarToday
              [(viewDate)]="viewDate">
              Today
            </div>
            <div
              class="btn btn-primary"
              mwlCalendarNextView
              [view]="view"
              [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
              (viewDateChange)="activeDayIsOpen = false">
              Next
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click) = 'redirectToAddMeeting()'> Add Meeting</button>

        </div>
    </div> 

  <mwl-calendar-month-view 
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [activeDayIsOpen]="true">
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: okay wait, but there are lots of dependencies. I have not used stackblitz before.

Comment: Ya I can't figure out stackblitz as I haven't use it before. The problem is that when I comment out the events the calendar will load completely but when I add events it would load partially and would only load on clicking on events. I think I need to tell angular to reload or refresh the view after my all events are loaded.

Comment: share your html

Comment: i have updated the qs with html code

Comment: instead of adding code in stackblitz check this link and share your code https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Comment: but do you have any idea how to refresh or re render view, when I am adding any events then only it is causing problem not otherwise. So after I add events how can I tell angular to reload calendar view

Comment: if it is not showing on ui side then try to use changedetectionref service

Comment: But how ? You can see that in my code I have used detectChanges()

Comment: try to use markForChanges method

Comment: Okay , thanks for sticking with me.